# Pass Props in a Private Route React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, mern

I'm trying to pass several props in a private route. What's the correct way to write this and what am I missing? Here is the code I have. My app works with this code, in that the user is able to login and see the dashboard. However, the props aren't passing. Is there a way to pass props to a private route?

```
   <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} render={routeProps =>
            <Dashboard
            handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
            book={this.state.book}
            info={this.state.info}
            {...routeProps} />}
          />
```

Dashboard Component

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

    state = {
        book: this.props.book,
        info: this.props.info, 
        error: '',
    }

    onLogoutClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.logoutUser();
    };

    render() {
    
    console.log(`BOOK STATE IN DB: ${this.state.book}`)
        
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    return(
            <div>
                <h4>
                    <b>This is your page</b> {user.name}
                </h4>
                <button onClick={this.onLogoutClick}>Logout</button>
                <h2>Search Book</h2>
                <Search 
                    handleUpdate={this.props.handleUpdate}
                />
                <h4>Book Results</h4>
                <div>{this.state.book}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
    logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { logoutUser }
)(Dashboard);
```

Private Route

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  console.log(auth),

  <Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    auth.isAuthenticated === false  ? (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
      
    ) : (
      <Component {...props} />
    )
  }
/>
);
PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, auth, book, handleUpdate, ...rest }) => (
  console.log(rest),
  console.log(book),

  <Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    auth.isAuthenticated === false  ? (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
  
) : (
  <Component book={book} handleUpdate={handleUpdate} {...props} />
)
```

}
/>
)

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the code of PrivateRouter component? You can just follow the such way

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} props = {{book: this.state.book etc}}/>
```

And receive this props on PrivateRoute components to put it into child component

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the `component={Dashboard}` prop, and only use the render prop to render the Dashboard. Your code should look like this

```
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" render={routeProps =>
            <Dashboard
            handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
            book={this.state.book}
            info={this.state.info}
            {...routeProps} />}
          />
```

Comment: I get this error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: The problem is the  how you exported and imported the ``Dashboard`` Component. Can you show the export code for the ``Dashboard`` component?

Comment: @Elizabeth The problem is not from export but the import of Dashboard. use ``import Dashboard from '../path-to-dashboard-component'``.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)

> **Warning**: `<Route component>` takes precedence over `<Route render>` so don’t use both in the same .

So, remove the `component={Dashboard}`

---

After the comments and the `PrivateRoute` code, i suggest you rewrite your `PrivateRoute` to

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ auth, ...rest }) => {
  if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }

  return <Route {...rest} />
);
```

and remove the `component={Dashboard}` part.

Comment: That's was my initial guess but it presents an error. I added the code for my private route and dashboard component above

Comment: @Elizabeth ok so you pass a `render` which is the one you want but in the `PrivateRoute` you overwrite it with another `render` method.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more and your suggestion?

Comment: Should I put the props in the PrivateRoute.js?

Comment: @Elizabeth your original code will take the `render` method you pass to `PrivateRoute` and it will pass it to the `Route` through the `rest` props. But right after the `{...rest}` that you do you also have another `render={...}` which will overwrite the one in the `rest` props. In my suggestion we only use the `auth` to check the authenitaction and all the rest props are passed to the `Route` to allow it to have its normal operation.